# Printing TERM, PATH & HOME Error! Bash

Tags: bash, unix

I have written a long script and part of it prints the values of the TERM, PATH and HOME Variables.

```
$Var1="$TERM"
echo "TERM $Var1"

$Var2="$PATH"
echo "PATH $Var2"

$Var3="$HOME"
echo "Home $Var3"
echo
```

However, in the script this is giving me this error:

```
userinfo.sh: line 55: =xterm: command not found
TERM
userinfo.sh: line 58: =/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/student/ch399/bin: No such file or directory
PATH
userinfo.sh: line 61: =/home/student/ch399: No such file or directory
Home
```

It is printing the values as I want it to, however it prints an error immediately afterwards. Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `$` from the initialization of the variables:

Change :

```
$Var1="$TERM"
echo "TERM $Var1"

$Var2="$PATH"
echo "PATH $Var2"

$Var3="$HOME"
echo "Home $Var3"
echo
```

to:

```
Var1="$TERM"
echo "TERM $Var1"

Var2="$PATH"
echo "PATH $Var2"

Var3="$HOME"
echo "Home $Var3"
echo
```

Answer (score 3):

you are doing it wrong ^^

```
$Var1="$TERM"
echo "TERM $Var1"
```

$Var1 : this **outputs** the content of variable Var1 (here it seems initially empty, so it will output: "")

$TERM : this **outputs** the content of variable XTERM (here you seem to have it set at: "xterm")

so you are saying to the shell:

```
 =$TERM
 echo "TERM "
```

which creates the outputs (1st is an error, 2nd is the echo) :

```
=xterm: command not found
TERM
```

You should instead use:

```
Var1="$TERM"
echo "TERM $Var1"
Var2="$PATH" 
(etc.)
```